# C# web service against Oracle database source which is sometimes unavailable

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, oracle10g

We have an existing big application which contains a lot of data.  We'd like to use it as a datasource for various internally written C# web applications, so we don't have more redundant data.

The data we are looking at doesn't change too much, so caching would work fine most of the time.  So we are writing a C# Web Service against the data to be reused in various internally written applications.

However roughly once per month, the Oracle database source is unavailable.

What is the best way to handle this in the web service so that those other applications that rely on that data aren't disrupted also?

Comment: What kind of web service? ASMX?

Comment: @John Saunders Yes at the moment, unless there's a better/easier way?  Should I use WCF instead?

Comment: Yes, use WCF for all new development. See [Microsoft says: ASMX Web Services are a "legacy technology"](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%E2%80%9Clegacy-technology%E2%80%9D/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use a secondary Cache which doesn't expires.
The secondary cache is updated with the latest values if the first (shorter) cache is  successfully updated from the database.  If the database querying fails and the first cache has expired, then the first cache is updated by the second cache.  So there is always a secondary cache.

Answer (score 1):

Set up replication or failover partners? Honestly, this doesn't seem like a job for more code; it sounds like a job for more infrastructure. I know Oracle licenses are expensive, but so is paying developers to work around unavailability.

If you simply had to solve it with code, then the web services should simply retain and return their cached data if any regularly-scheduled DB query fails with a timeout or connection failed-type message. The cached data should be kept as long as necessary in this circumstance, until a call to refresh that data succeeds. If there is no cached data, you can either swallow the error and return nothing, or return an error stating the data is unavailable from both places.